# Extract only month from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I've a SQl Query. I'm using dropdownlist to display the dates. I'd like to display the month in MMMM format.

```
SELECT DISTINCT[drdates] (CONVERT(CHAR(4), [drdates], 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [drdates], 120)) FROM [DRReceive_20141229]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,MONTH([drdates])),4)) 
               + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [drdates], 120)
FROM [DRReceive_20141229]
```

On a side note I have never seen date values being formatted as MMMMyyyy, a rather strange format to show date values.

But if you wanted something rather simple or usual format like `MMMyyyy` and if you are using sql server 2012 or later version you can do the following ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(FORMAT ( [drdates], 'MMMyyyy' ))
FROM [DRReceive_20141229]
```

Comment: I get Arithmetic Overflow error when executing the first query and FORMAT is not built-in recognized function name

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to retrieve months first four characters :

```
  select CONVERT(CHAR(4),DATENAME(MONTH, [drdates])) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),[drdates], 120)) [DRReceive_20141229];
```